# Comparison of population sizes

Tags: probability, distributions, statistical-significance, normal-distribution

To break my problem down simply,

Company A employs 50 people , with 2 people likely to be in an accident.
Company B employs 400 people with 40 people likely to be in an accident.

I'm struggling to understand if I can compare the 2 sample sizes fairly?

i.e Is it fair to compare a company with size of 50 people against a company with size of 400 people and what statistic I can use?

I was looking at significance and p-value, same with distribution, but not entirely sure?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, the difference in the variance of the estimates due to their differing sample sizes takes it into account.

Answer (score 0):

Comment: It depends on what you mean by 'likely to be' in an accident. You need
to explain what you mean and the basis for your statements about
actual accidents or accident rates.

**Data:** If you have data, then you can do a test. For example, last year if A had 2 people with accidents and 48 without, while B had 40 people with accidents and 360 without, then Fisher's exact test would not find a significant difference, mainly because of the small amount of data
from A:

```
TBL = cbind(c(2,48), c(40,360));  TBL
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2   40
[2,]   48  360

fisher.test(TBL)

        Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  TBL
p-value = 0.2057
alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.04263549 1.53123088
sample estimates:
odds ratio 
 0.3755898
```

**Specified Poisson rates.** If you somehow know that the Poisson accident rate at A is $\lambda = 2/50 = 0.04$ per employee, then the probability any one employee will have
at least one accident in the following year is $0.0392.$

```
1 - dpois(0,2/50)
[1] 0.03921056
```

And for B the same kind of computation leads to a the higher
probability $0.0952.$

```
1 - dpois(0,40/400)
[1] 0.09516258
```

Both probability computations assume that each employee has the same risk of
accident, which is doubtful.